# variable AS (SELECT...) SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a very silly question, but I keep bashing myself off the wall and I can't figure out even what exactly to google.

I have a database, and I am doing some SQL-queries. This one is working fine.

```
SELECT 
year(datetime_buy), 
month(datetime_buy), 
count(distinct email) AS number
FROM ticket
WHERE year(datetime_buy)=2018
AND email IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM ticket 
    WHERE Month(datetime_buy)=1
    AND Year(datetime_buy)=2018 AND datetime_cancel IS NULL)
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

But when I am trying to save some `SELECT` for the future (such as `jan_tickets`):

```
jan_tickets AS (
SELECT DISTINCT email 
FROM ticket 
WHERE Month(datetime_buy)=1
AND Year(datetime_buy)=2018
AND datetime_cancel IS NULL),

SELECT
year(datetime_buy),
month(datetime_buy),
count(distinct email) AS number
FROM ticket
WHERE year(datetime_buy)=2018
AND email IN jan_tickets
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'jan_tickets AS (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM ticket
WHERE Month(datetime_buy)=1 AN' at line 1
```

Update: I use MySQL 5.6.

Comment: `WITH jan_tickets AS ( ... ) SELECT year(datetime_buy) ...` You need to preface a CTE definition with `WITH` (at least the first one), and there is no comma after the CTE definition before the actual query.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question and the expected output.  It seems that your question has a second part, and even the corrected query is not giving you what you want here.

Comment: You haven't "saved" anything "for the future". You merely tried to move the subquery to the front of the query, which is just another way of writing the same thing. Are you looking for `CREATE VIEW` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were running MySQL 8+, then the following update to your would work:

```
WITH jan_tickets AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT email
    FROM ticket
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetime_buy, '%Y-%m') = '2018-01' AND datetime_cancel IS NULL
)

SELECT
    YEAR(datetime_buy),
    MONTH(datetime_buy),
    COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS number
FROM ticket
WHERE
    YEAR(datetime_buy) = 2018 AND
    email IN (SELECT email FROM jan_tickets)
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Notes here include that a CTE definition has to begin using `WITH`.  Subsequence CTEs that follow do *not* use `WITH`, but should be separated by comma.  There is no comma after the last CTE definition, before the query which consumes it.  In your case, you need a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which selects emails from the CTE.

**Edit:**

Since you are only using MySQL 5.6, you can't use common table expressions.  So, we may inline the subquery contained in the CTE:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(datetime_buy),
    MONTH(datetime_buy),
    COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS number
FROM ticket
WHERE
    YEAR(datetime_buy) = 2018 AND
    email IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT email
        FROM ticket
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetime_buy, '%Y-%m') = '2018-01' AND
              datetime_cancel IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: I tried your code and I still got the same error. I use MySQL 5.6 if that matters.

Comment: You are running MySQL 5.6 which does not support CTE.  Let me update my question with something which should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but that is my original solution. The problem is that now it is only one month, but I would like to check, for example, May, and I need to exclude all emails from previous 4 months, and it is just copy-paste of the code and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: you do not need to use DISTINCT in IN clause